# tracing the sequence of linux processes scheduled

Tags: linux, process, scheduling

In Linux, which tool would help me see the sequence in which the processes are scheduled.

Comment: Why do you care? The scheduler works at very fine grain (e.g. 50 times per second). Notice that such a tool, if it is a user-level application, would be scheduled itself...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I just want to see the change in sequence for different priorities of a process. Any way to go about it? Would 'printk' be of use?

Comment: Just observing the scheduler would certainly change its behavior! Your millions of `printk` (I'm not sure it is safe to call from inside the scheduler) would for instance load `syslogd` a lot and it would be scheduled very differently.

Comment: Yeah, your right, millions of printk. Any tool or anything that would help me with this?

Comment: No. But you should not care about that. You could simply use `top` to see which process are running, and how much they are loading the CPU

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I disagree. I am using cset to move all processes away from certain cores, disabled the IRQ balacing, and should now only have 1 process running on 1 particular core (hyper threading disabled). And yet there are still other processes (kernel level) getting scheduled. And I would like to know which ones, to know whether I can stop them, or move them to another core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that tool would be "perf", specifically, "perf sched". See http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/Documentation/perf-sched.txt for details